# What is the best way to load an image dynamically without going back to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I've got a very simple card game built in ASP-MVC.

One element of the game is the ability to pick a random card from a deck of 52.

I've got 52 svg's representing the deck and some JavaScript that generates a random number.

What I'd like to happen is when the user clicks the deck a random card pops up somewhere on the screen.

Code so far:

```
<div>
    <img src="~/images/poker/poker-deck.svg" onclick="pickCard()" />
</div>
<div>
    <img id="imgCard" alt="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function pickCard() {

        document.getElementById("imgCard").src = "images/poker/poker-" +   Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1 + ".svg";
    }  

</script>
```

Unfortunately all that happens at the moment is a broken image icon gets displayed.

I'm assuming the image is still on the server not available to the browser hence why I get the broken link.

I don't want to go back to the server if I can help it. One thing I'm considering is loading all 52 cards into the page and using CSS to hide and show as appropriate.

Is there a better/simpler way to achieve the same result?

Additional Info:

Error from DevTools: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:59862/images/poker/poker-01.svg

Comment: In the end this came down to human error. The image was named: poker-1.svg not poker-01.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your diagnosis is wrong. I think that the reason of your issue is that you use `~` (tilde) as a part of the path. This is not a part of HTML-standard, this is a thing that is supported by IIS/ASP.NET (and some other web-servers). For browser you should actually put absolute or relative URL.

To check if I'm right just open your page in modern browser, open "dev tools" and see network request for images. I expect you get HTTP error 404 (Not Found) and thus "a broken image icon gets displayed". Just look at what URL the browser actually tries to open for the image.

Yes, you might push your images inside CSS using [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) but I don't think you really need this right now. Just put proper URL and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The tilde was a good spot I think you're half right. So I just ran the site up in chrome, got the 404, but even when I correct the path the image still isn't returned for any resource that hasn't already been loaded on the page. For example I can now get the JavaScript to return the deck of cards but not the others images still on the server. When looking under sources > images in dev tools only the image for the deck of cards is available.

Comment: @Freddie2025, I'm not sure I understand your new problem. Browsers are lazy by default and don't fetch resources until they are need (but you can and should configure caching to avoid re-download on each page re-load). So what doesn't work as you expect it? What are those "other images" and how exactly "you can't get the JavaScript to return the others images"?

Comment: I think you have solved the problem in a way. What I need to do is load/cache my resources. Is the link you gave me to Data URI scheme a way I can achieve this?

Comment: @Freddie2025 It is really hard to give reasonable advices when you avoid stating what your actual problem is and just asking questions about your partial solution. Yes, you may use `data` URI scheme to put all your images into CSS or even HTML. Whether this is a good or bad idea depends on a lot of details.

Comment: So the other images are the 52 playing cards in the deck that currently are not referenced anywhere in the website. They only exist in the images folder on the server. I want to be able to access these images so when I make a call with JavaScript they appear on the page. One solution I had was to embed all 52 images in the webpage and use CSS to hide or show them. I then asked if there were alternative\better solutions. I appreciate "better" is subjective. I'm really looking for standard\best practice. If there many different approaches I'd like to hear them so I can decide on a best approach.

Comment: @Freddie2025, you still don't state where you see the problem! Yes, originally all images are located only on the server, so whay? Where exactly this becomes a problem with "I want to be able to access these images so when I make a call with JavaScript they appear on the page"? How is this case different from yout `pickCard` JavaScript? Doesn't it show an image that is origianlly located on the server only? As for alternatives, one more quite popular one is using `CSS sprites` and that can be done with SVG as well (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/resolution-independence-with-svg/)

Comment: The problem is I'm still getting a broken image link in the imgCard placeholder. The poker-deck.svg image (acting as the button) displays without issue. When the JavaScript is called to try and retrieve any of the other images I get a broken link in the imgCard placeholder. However if I replace the string + random number code in the JavaScript with the poker-deck.svg it shows up on screen. Obviously the poker-deck gets downloaded from the server when IIS/Browser renders the page, hence the resource is available, but the rest of the cards are not. CSS sprites may well resolve this.

Comment: @Freddie2025, update question and show your actual code. Also, what is exactly your actual "broken URL". You again can see it using DevTools. Most probably you have some bug in your JS logic.

Comment: So I removed the tilde as you suggested, but apart from that all I've got is another div and a tiny bit of razor syntax setting the title of the page. What else do you want to see? The controller, the layout page. I really don't think that's going to be very helpful. I'll see if I can get some more info from dev tools and update the question.

Comment: I've just worked out what was wrong, it was my stupid human error, the svg was name poker-1 not poker-01. I'm going to mark your answer as accepted. Thank you so much for all your help, if nothing else you've taught me about CSS sprites and to be more careful before I submit a question to SO.